# Mostrar valores com angular

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
$http.get('/estados').success(function(retorno) {
    $scope.ufs = retorno.ufs;
    console.log(retorno);
});
```

e o resultado do `console.log(retorno)` é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora estou tentando mostrar os valores deste retorno em um `<select>` do HTML:

```
<section class="input-field col l1 s12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">public</i>
    <select name="uf" required="true">
        <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in ufs">[{value.sigla}]</option>
    </select>
</section>
```

Porém não está mostrando valor nenhum, mas ao inspecionar o elemento vejo o código abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele está atribuindo os valores aos `<option>` do `<select>` porém na página para o cliente selecionar não aparece nada.

Alguém já passo por isso?

OBS: Estou usado `{[` porque troquei nas configs.

```
app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{').endSymbol('}]'); 
});
```

Comment: Quando você da faz isso: `console.log(retorno.ufs)` qual o resultado?

Comment: Tenta colocar o ng-repeat no select

Comment: @Techies o resultado de `console.log(retorno.ufs) é igual, so muda que na primeira linha fica `[Object, Object....]`

Comment: Tentou colocar o ng-repeat no select? @MeuChapeu

Comment: não funciona no select

Comment: @Techies acredito que o problema não esteja relacionado com o angular visto que as options foram geradas corretamente.

Comment: @Oeslei sim, eu estava imaginando o mesmo, só queria ter 100% de certeza rs

Comment: Eu particularmente uso o ng-options no select: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 1):

`ufs` é um *array*, não um objeto com chaves e valores.

Ao invés de utilizar

```
<option ng-repeat="(key, value) in ufs">[{value.sigla}]</option>
```

Tente

```
<option ng-repeat="value in ufs">{{value.sigla}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está usando [] no binding do `value`. Você está fazendo dessa forma:

```
[{value.sigla}]
```

O correto seria utilizar `{{value.sigla}}`

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/81t6cbjw/25/

Comment: Eu mudei as configs de `{{` para `{[`

Comment: Não entendi @MeuChapeu

Comment: Desconfio que seja algo do frameworks `css` o materialize, pq desabilitando funciona...

Comment: No meu código tenho: `app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
 $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{').endSymbol('}]');
});` o que me permite usar `{[` ao invés de `{{`.

Comment: Ah sim, agora entendi.

Comment: Tenta dar uma modificada na ordem das declarações das bibliotecas

Answer (score 0):

Cara já tentei utilizar isso ai

```
$http.get('/estados').success(function(retorno) {
    $scope.ufs = retorno.ufs;
    console.log(retorno);
});
```

Da uma olhada no ngResource, um exemplo que fiz no meu service.

```
 var services = angular.module('ProcessoService', ['ngResource']);

    services.factory('ProcessosFactory', function($resource,apiUrl){
      var resource = $resource('http://restTest/retornos');

      var factory = {
          listar: function () {        
              var lista = resource.query({}, function(data){
                 lista = data;
              });
              return lista;
          }


      }


  return factory;
```

no controller só chama:

```
$scope.lista = ProcessosFactory.listar();
```

no html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="processo in processos">
            <td>{{ processo.id }}</td>
<tr>
```

vê se ajuda no seu caso.